# How to calculate $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \exp\left(-x^2-y^2+ixy-ix-iy\right)\,dx\,dy$?

Tags: calculus, integration, gaussian-integral

How do you calculate the following? $$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \exp\left(-x^2-y^2+ixy-ix-iy\right)\,dx\,dy$$ It might be solved by representing $x$ and $y$ with a pair of other variables but I have no idea.

Comment: Is the integration range $\mathbb{R}^2$? Is $i$ the imaginary unit or just some real constant?

Comment: The integration rangle is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Comment: Sorry for that I didn't view this page until now. I confuse the concepts of indefinite integral and definite integral with a whole $xy$-plane range....So "indefinite integral" is a wrong tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Gaussian double-integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)
$$ I ~:=~\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \! dx~dy~ e^{-S(x,y)} ,\tag{1} $$
where 
$$ S(x,y)~:=~x^2+y^2-ixy+ix+iy. \tag{2}$$
One method is to change coordinates $x^{\pm}=\frac{x\pm y}{\sqrt{2}}$ and [complete the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square). However computationally it is easier to just use the [method of steepest descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent) which yields exact results for Gaussian integrals. The stationary point is 
$$(x_0,y_0)~=~ \left(\frac{1}{1+2i},\frac{1}{1+2i}\right). \tag{3}$$
The integral therefore becomes
$$ I~=~\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\det(S^{\prime\prime}(x_0,y_0))}} e^{-S(x_0,y_0)}
~=~\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{5}} \exp\left(\frac{1}{i-2}\right).\tag{4}$$